# PDF bookmarks for enumerate items

Tags: pdf, enumitem, bookmarks

I'm trying to insert PDF bookmarks for enumerate items:

I've defined a custom list type `exercises` that almost works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[exercises,1]{left=-2\parindent .. -\parindent,label=\protect\pdfbookmark[1]{Exercise \arabic*}{ex-\arabic*}\arabic*., ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[exercises,2]{left=0pt .. \parindent,label=\protect\pdfbookmark[2]{Part \alph*}{ex-\arabic{exercisesi}-part\alph*}\alph*), ref=\arabic{exercisesi}.~\alph*)}
\crefname{exercisesi}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{exercisesii}{exercise}{exercises}
\creflabelformat{exercisesii}{#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}
    \item \label{part:1} \begin{exercises}
        \item \label{part:1a}
            This is \cref{part:1a}

            Second line
        \item B
        \newpage
        \item c
    \end{exercises}
    \item \label{part:2} \begin{exercises}
        \item \label{part:2a}
            That was \cref{part:1a}

            Second line
        \item B
        \item c
    \end{exercises}
\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this has two problems:

1. The bookmarks contain extra items at the begining, `0` for `\arabic` and `m` for `\alph`
   [image]
2. Clicking a PDF bookmark scrolls to the baseline of the first line of the item, which is one line too low.

How should I be doing this?